# Custom delimiter in message modelling in IBM Integration Bus in V9.0.0.0

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, bus

Hi I need to create one message model for my data in the IBM integration Bus

my message structure is as below

abcd:FMxyz:VMsad:SVMfksdf:SVMlksdflkl:VM:FMxyz:VMsad:SVMfksdf:SVMlksdflkl

:FM is the field marker
:VM is the value marker
:SVM is the sub value marker these are three different Characters.
Data has to be extracted using these delimiters.

I need to have three different delimiters in IIB while creating the message model. 
Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you are having trouble? The DFDL editor will allow you to have different sets of delimiters for any type.

It might help if you show a tree representation of what you expect the logical model to look like for the example string you have given.

Comment: Hi Dave, consider the message 


abcd:FMxyz:VMsad:SVMfksdf:SVMlksdflkl:VM:FMxyz:VMsad:SVMfksdf:SVMlksdflkl

Comment: Hi Dave, consider the message 


abcd:FMxyz:VMsad:SVMfksdf:SVMlksdflkl:VM:FMabc       In this the message structure which we want is   <FieldValue1>  abcd</FieldValue1>   <FieldValue2><Value1>XYZ</Value1><SubValue1>sad</SubValue1><SubValue2>fksdf</Subvalue2>SubValue2>lksdflkl</Subvalue2></FieldValue2><FieldValue3>abc<FieldValue3>

Comment: To give a deeper understanding is this data is from a multivalue database which can have multivalues in a single field which is mutually separated by Field marker which separated each filed then there is value marker which separated the values within fields and the there is sub value marker which is used for further segregating the values